# Multi-thread loop not ending in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

I wrote (copied and adapted) a python program to do some backups.  It basically reads the files from a source location and copies or creates hard links in a destination.  It is multi-threaded and that part works ok.  The problem is that the loop that is called in the threads never ends.  The relevant code is below.  I read that it might be one of the threads raising an error and hanging but don't know how to check that.  The program reads from a file queue, process the files, then is supposed to end.  It reads and processes the files till the queue is empty and then just hangs.  Any suggestions on what to try or to look at?  hopefully i pasted enough code to help

```
print ("beginning backup")
backup(path_to_source, path_to_full, dest_path, backup_type)
print ("Backup finished")

# --- clean full backup
if backup_type == "Full":
    print ("Cleaning up full backup - deleting deleted files")
    clean_backup()
    print ("Backup has been cleaned.  Done")

#--------------------------------------------------
def backup(path_to_source, path_to_full, dest_path, backup_type):
    threadWorkerCopyInc(source_files)
     print ("All Done")   #(never executes)

def threadWorkerCopyInc(fileNameList):
    global num_threads
    #fileQueue = queue.queue()
    for i in range(num_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=IncCopyWorker)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        #threads.append(t)
    for fileName in fileNameList:
        fileQueue.put(fileName)
    fileQueue.join()
    #for i in range(len(threads)):
    #    fileQueue.put('None')
    #for t in threads:
    #    t.join()
    print('done with threadworkercopyinc')   #(never executes)


def IncCopyWorker():
    print ('Starting IncCopyWorker. ')   #executes
           
    while True:
        
        filename = fileQueue.get()
        if filename == 'None':
            print("\nFilename is none")  #executes when fileQueue.qsize() = 0
            
        with threadlock: processedfiles +=1
        print ("Files to go: %d  processed files:  %d  newfiles: %d  hardlinks: %d not copied: %d dfsr: %d  " %(fileQueue.qsize(), processedfiles, newfiles, hardlinks, notcopied, dfsr), end = '\r')
       
        is_dfsr = filename.upper().find("DFSR")
       
        if (is_dfsr == -1): 
              #do main processing here
        else:
            with threadlock: dfsr+=1
        fileQueue.task_done()
    print ("done with while true loop")  #never Executes
```

Comment: How is your `while True` loop supposed to end?

Comment: I see i missed some code.  Basically after the while true loop ends i want it to continue on in my code.  I basically want it to get back to the line print ("all Done").  I actually have other code to execute there so if i can get there it would be great.  I am going to see if i can edit my code

Comment: The way i understand it when fileQueue is empty the thread will automatically end and when all the threads end the program should continue.  I am basing this off of looking at multiple examples so i could be wrong.  I tried doing break in the filename==none block but it did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like my problem was that i included continue statements in my try/except blocks to try and speed up execution.  When there is a continue or break statement the loop never ended.  When i took out the continue statements it finished the way it was supposed to.  I don't know the reason -just the solution